# How can I cancel an asynchronous delegate in C# 3.5?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

I have searched google up and down but I can not find nearly any proper information about that topic.

What I wanna do is this:

1. User types a single search-string in a textbox.
2. I wait 0.5 s then I start to BeginInvoke my delegate pointing to a search method.
3. If the user types again a char I want to cancel the Search and begin a new search with the new string typed.
4. The UI-Thread must not be blocked!

How can I do that using C# 3.5 ?

**UPDATE**:

**View**:

```
private void OnTextChanged(...)
{
   if (SearchFormatEvent != null)
   {
       ICollection<object> collection = SearchFormatEvent("MySearchString");
       // Do stuff on the returned collection                            
    }
}
```

**SearchProvider**:

```
// This is the delegate invoked for the async search taking the searchstring typed by the user
    public delegate ICollection<object> SearchInputTextStrategy<T>(string param);

    public class SearchProvider : ISearchProvider
    {
        private ITextView _view;
        private SearchInputTextStrategy<object> searchInputDelegate;

        public SearchProvider(ITextView view)
        {
            _view = view;
            _view.SearchFormatEvent += new ConstructSearchFormatDelegate(CostructSearchFormat);
        } 

        private string SearchFormat(string param)
        { 
            // compute string

            return string.Empty; //...
        }

        public ICollection<object> CostructSearchFormat(string param)
        {
            var searchfilter = SearchFormat(param);

             IAsyncResult pendingOperation = searchInputDelegate.BeginInvoke("searchfilter",null,null);

            // How can I cancel the Async delegate ?

            ICollection<object> result = searchInputDelegate.EndInvoke(pendingOperation);

            return result;                
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you spawning the background search method?

Comment: I have updated a code sample! see above!

Comment: You can't stop the execution of a non cooperating function in a clean way. You need a flag which this function regularly checks. `CancellationToken` does this in .net 4, no idea if there is a built-in class in 3.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch  to BackGroudWorker , is supports all you need ( NoUI Blocking , Cancellation ect, Progress Reporting..)

Comment: @Pascal - can you share your source-code for the complete solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [CancellationTokenSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.aspx) and [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.asp), it is a thread safe method to signal cancellation.

You use the `CancellationTokenSource` to signal Cancellation to all owners of `CancellationToken` (the search thread in your case)